# Collision conflict of object between 2 mobile robots

Tags: gazebo, gazebo-plugin, gazebo-model

I'm trying to use gazebo to simulate 2 robots to cooperate transport the pallet but the pallet keep break through the fork when both robots push the pallet.

[image]

[image]

[image]

here's my collision parameter for my pallet

```
<collision>
  <origin
    xyz="0 0 0"
    rpy="0 0 0" />
  <geometry>
    <mesh
      filename="file:///$(find my_robot_description)/meshes/pallet/base_link.STL" />
  </geometry>
  <surface>
    <contact friction="0.01"> 
    <poissons_ratio>0.347</poissons_ratio>
    <elastic_modulus>8.8e+09</elastic_modulus>
    <ode>
      <soft_cfm>0.2</soft_cfm>
      <soft_erp>2e+20</soft_erp>
      <kp>1</kp>
      <kd>1</kd>
      <max_vel>0.01</max_vel>
      <min_depth>0.1</min_depth>
    </ode>
    </contact>
    <friction>
        <fdir1>0 0 0</fdir1>
        <mu>0.5</mu>
        <slip2>0</slip2>
        <mu2>0.5</mu2>
        <slip1>0</slip1>
    </friction>
  </surface>
  <contact_coefficients mu ="1" kp="1e15" kd="1"/> 
</collision>
```

For more information about my robot
1.Ackermann steering robot control with gaze_ros_planar_move plugin
2.DIffDrive control with gazebo_ros_diff_drive
I've tried change the gazebo_ros_planar_move plugin to gazebo_ros2_control with a differential drive controller , but the problem still exist.

I've found this one similar problem : https://answers.gazebosim.org//question/21895/ur5-robot-breaks-after-small-collision/ but it's a manipulator, so I don't know how to fix collision if it's 2 mobile robots